# Can't I add a list to my models.py in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm quite new in Django and in this project I need to manage information about a restaurant. The problem is that I can't add more than one ingredient required to a recipe

[image: Photo of the problem]

My `models.py` is this:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
    
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    unit_price = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class MenuItem(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    price = models.FloatField()
    example = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class RecipeRequirement(models.Model):
    menu_items = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, default = 1,  on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    ingredient = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    quantity = models.FloatField()
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.menu_items)


class Purchase(models.Model):
    menu_item = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, default=1, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Purchase ' + str(self.menu_item) + str(self.timestamp)
```

After replacing `ingredients = models.CharField()` for `ingredients = models.ManyToManyField()` a list of all ingredients appear:

[image]

But when I add a new ingredient to my `Ingredient` model, it automatically appears in every single `menu_item`:

[image]

Comment: In your example image, you mean Ingredient id is 2 ? And you want to be able to pass many ingredients id there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a ManyToMany relationship in your RecipeRequirement model. This will allow you to select multiple ingredients for any one RecipeRequirement object. Read more here: [Django ManyToMany Fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

```
class RecipeRequirement(models.Model):
    menu_items = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, default = 1,  on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)
    quantity = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.menu_items)
```

Comment: That's a progress. But when I do this, I must use all of the ingredients I added.

Comment: Not necessarily, a ManyToMany field will allow any value from 0 (none) to any number of related objects (ingredients in this case) to be selected as related to the RecipeRequirement object.

Comment: Can you give an example of the issue perhaps?

Comment: List of the needed ingredients to Django Djaffa Cake: Egg, Cane Sugar, Flour and Milk Chocolate. But if in ingredients I create another one like 'butter', it automatically appears in my Django Djaffa Cake recipe

Comment: Please share a screenshot of the Django Admin. Just because it shows up in the admin list, does not mean it is actually selected. You have to select one or multiple ingredients to actually create the relation. 

By default, no ingredients will be selected, although all of them will be listed.

Comment: Problem solved, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Set ingredients in the RecipeRequirement class as a ManyToMany field on the Ingredient class:

```
class RecipeRequirement(models.Model):
    menu_items = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, default = 1,  on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)
    quantity = models.FloatField()
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.menu_items)
```

Comment: Good, but if a do this, django says  that I must use all ingredients i added.

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of what you are seeing? It would make it easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your `Ingredient`class must have a `ForeignKey` associated with the `RecipeRequirement` in order to add more than one ingredient related to the recipe.

I suggest using a website like https://drawsql.app/ in order to obtain a better visualization of your database relationships.